# Parallelizing scipy csr sparse matrices for big matrix multiplication using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I am computing cosine similarity between two large sets of vectors (with the same features). Each set of vectors is represented as a scipy CSR sparse matrix, A and B. **I want to compute A x B^T**, which will not be sparse. However, I only need to keep track of values exceeding some threshold, e.g. 0.8. I am trying to implement this in Pyspark with vanilla RDDs, with the idea of using the fast vector operations implemented for scipy CSR matrices.

The rows of A and B are normalized, so to compute cosine similarity I simply need to find the dot product of each row from A with each row from B.
The dimensions of A are 5,000,000 x 5,000. 
The dimensions of B are 2,000,000 x 5,000.

Suppose A and B are too large to fit into memory on my worker nodes as broadcast variables. How should I approach parallelizing both A and B in an optimal way?

*EDIT*
After I posted my solution, I have been exploring other approaches which may be clearer and more optimal, particularly the columnSimilarities() function implemented for Spark MLlib IndexedRowMatrix objects. ([Which pyspark abstraction is appropriate for my large matrix multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297660/which-pyspark-abstraction-is-appropriate-for-my-large-matrix-multiplication))

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement a solution in this framework.
Would welcome insight into why this solution is slow--is it the custom serialization?

```
def csr_mult_helper(pair):
    threshold=0.8
    A_row = pair[0][0]  # keep track of the row offset
    B_col = pair[1][0]   # offset for B (this will be a column index, after the transpose op)
    A = sparse.csr_matrix(pair[0][1], pair[0][2])  # non-zero entires, size data
    B = sparse.csr_matrix(pair[1][1], pair[1][2])

    C = A * B.T  # scipy sparse mat mul

    for row_idx, row in enumerate(C):  # I think it would be better to use a filter Transformation instead
        col_indices = row.indices      #  but I had trouble with the row and column index book keeping
        col_values = row.data

        for col_idx, val in zip(col_indices, col_values):
            if val > threshold:
                yield (A_row + row_idx, B_col + col_idx, val)  # source vector, target vector, cosine score            

def parallelize_sparse_csr(M, rows_per_chunk=1):
    [rows, cols] = M.shape
    i_row = 0
    submatrices = []
    while i_row < rows:
        current_chunk_size = min(rows_per_chunk, rows - i_row)
        submat = M[i_row:(i_row + current_chunk_size)]
        submatrices.append(   (i_row,                                #  offset
                              (submat.data, submat.indices, submat.indptr),  # sparse matrix data
                              (current_chunk_size, cols)) )      # sparse matrix shape
        i_row += current_chunk_size
    return sc.parallelize(submatrices)

########## generate test data ###########
K,L,M,N = 5,2000,3,2000  # matrix dimensions (toy example)
A_ = sparse.rand(K,L, density=0.1, format='csr')
B_ = sparse.rand(M,N, density=0.1, format='csr')
print("benchmark: {} \n".format((A_ * B_.T).todense()))  # benchmark solution for comparison

########## parallelize, multiply, and filter #########
t_start = time.time()
A = parallelize_sparse_csr(A_, rows_per_chunk=10)
B = parallelize_sparse_csr(B_, rows_per_chunk=10) # number of elements per partition, from B
            # warning: this code breaks if the B_ matrix rows_per_chunk parameter != 1
            # although I don't understand why yet

print("custom pyspark solution: ")
result = A.cartesian(B).flatMap(csr_mult_helper).collect()
print(results)

print("\n {} s elapsed".format(time.time() - t_start))
```